# can the Smarty templating engine show &euro; HTML entity

Tags: php, templates, smarty, php-5.3

I am having issues with the Smarty templating engine where I can't show `&euro;` for €, but I can use the older, `&#0128;`.

Does Smarty have issues representing this character?

Comment: How does the generated HTML look like? That's all what matters..

Comment: My HTML is very simple. This works: `<td class="description">&#0128;{$cart.price|number_format:2}</td>`, whereas this doesn't `<td class="description">&euro;{$cart.price|number_format:2}</td>`. Is this an issue with my encoding?

Comment: The *generated* HTML. Not the template sourcecode. If both contain the proper entities, it's not related to smarty.

Comment: I have found the issue. I generate HTML with Smarty and then pass it to DOMPDF to generate a PDF document. It appears to be DOMPDF that can only display `&#0128;` and not any other variant for the € symbol. This is found in their FAQs - http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/wiki/FAQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a matter of html and encoding, Smarty doesn't care about that

Answer (score 1):

No, smarty does not care about the characters you use.

However, I would use the proper UTF8 char instead of an entity.